# ошибка при установке expo-cli

Tags: expo

при установке expo-cli выдаёт ошибку npm ERR! errno -4048
версия node - 13.12.0

`npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Artist\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinApi.dll
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Artist\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinApi.dll'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Artist\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinApi.dll'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Artist\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinApi.dll'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\Artist\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\@expo\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\AdbWinApi.dll'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\\Users\\Artist\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\@expo\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\AdbWinApi.dll'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Artist\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\@expo\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\AdbWinApi.dll',
npm ERR!   parent: 'expo-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.`